# How can I redirect all traffic to one domain to the same location at another domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect all traffic to one domain to another. No matter what the subdomain or directory within. It should go to the same place at this other domain.

zweeue.com -> zoeyt.com

s.zweeue.com -> s.zoeyt.com

zweeue.com/art/ -> zoeyt.com/art/

Now here's the trick, at the other domain, I have a mod rewrite that sends all traffic for files and directories that do not exist to l.php

So zoeyt.com/art exists so zweeue.com/art/ would go to zoeyt.com/art/

But zweeue.com/mvs does not so zoeyt.com/mvs would go to zoeyt.com/mvs/. Right now, zweeue.com/mvs get a 404, but zweeue.com/art/ should go to zoeyt.com/art/ because /art/ exists there. Everything at zweeue.com goes to zoeyt.com with the below first htaccess file. The second mod rewrite block below is the seperate htaccess file on the seperate host for zoeyt.com

**How can I do this successfully? Currently zweeue.com/mvs goes to zoeyt.com/ and not zoeyt.com/mvs, which zoeyt's htaccess would send to l.php.**

Here is what is in the redirect htaccess at the first domain, zweeue.com:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.zoeyt.com/$1 [L,R=301]

</IfModule>
```

Here is what is in the second domain's htacccess file (zoeyt):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ /l.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: @anubhava Yes on two separate hosts

Comment: ok, did you try to test it using a new browser or command line `curl` to avoid old caching?

Comment: @anubhava Yes, of course.

Comment: @anubhava zweeue.com/art/ just goes to zoeyt.com. Not /art.

Comment: @anubhava Sorry, I should clarify, it should go to zoeyt.com/art, but it currently only goes to zoety.com

Comment: @anubhava I updated the question

Comment: ok can you run `curl -IL 'http://zweeue.com/art/'` command from your command line and paste it's output in question.

Comment: Also try this rule in 1st .htaccess `RewriteRule ^ http://www.zoeyt.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]`

Comment: @anubhava HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 09 Nov 2017 15:29:39 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://www.zweeue.com/art
X-Served-By: Namecheap URL Forward

curl: (52) Empty reply from server

Comment: @anubhava No, my server is apache, but I don't have shell access. I ran the command on my local machine.

Comment: @anubhava Thank you, that rule worked. Not sure how it is so different than what I had, but it worked. Can you please write it as the answer so I can post it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Change your first .htaccess to this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^ http://www.zoeyt.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

</IfModule>
```

Second domain's htacccess file (zoeyt):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ l.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Use of `%{REQUEST_URI}` instead of `$1` ensures you send full URI to target not a relative value captured in `$1`.